# Undefined symbols for architecture XXX - in Xcode 12.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode12

My `iOS` project was running just fine on `Xcode` until I gave in to `Apple`'s constant pressure to upgrade my `Xcode`, So I did. To `Xcode 12.1`, and out of absolute no where, the compiler refuses to build the project with something that looks like this:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`

I want to make my self blatantly clear. **This is not a specific framework issue!!!** Each time I compile, the compiler is blaming this on a different framework than the previous build. so it clearly seems like something more on the `IDE` level.

Here's what I have done till now:

- clean + build
- closed + reopened `Xcode`
- rebooted the computer
- deleted `derived data`
- `pod deintegrate` + `pod install`

Needless to say, none of this is working. it's worth mentioning that on one of our computers, I managed to solve the issue by randomly doing all those steps above, but on another machine, none is working.

I repeat, all this occurring **only** when upgrading to `Xcode 12.1`.

I have come across seemingly similar questions lately in various websites, but all are focusing on a specific framework they have been using, when in my case (not the first machine) it's a cross platform issue.

Before filing a bug to `Apple`, I would be more than happy to be corrected.

If you got till here, thanks for taking your time to read my issue :). it's an utterly annoying one. (sorry for the long speech)

Comment: Show your Podfile, otherwise it will be almost impossible to diagnose anything.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was solved by turning off "Parallelize Build" option. The problem occurred only on the Macbook Pro 16 inch, but it seems to be because there are many cores.

Try it like this:

1. Tap "Scheme" next to your build button.
2. Go to "Edit Scheme" > "Build".
3. Uncheck "Parallelize Build".